# Let $a,x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $ax ≡ 1 \mod n$. Prove that $a$ is coprime to $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $a,x \in  \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $ax ≡ 1
>   \mod n$. Prove that $a$ is coprime to $n$.

I have shown that $1=ax-ny$ for some $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ but I don't know if this is sufficient? (I.e. if Bezout's lemma is an $\iff$ situation)?

Help please.

Comment: $d\mid\color{#c00}{a,n}\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid \color{#c00}ax\!-\!\color{#c00}ny = 1,\,$ i.e $\,d\mid 1,\,$ so $\,a,n\,$ have only $\,d=\pm1\,$ as common divisors.

Comment: Beautiful answer.

Answer (score 2):

With $d=\gcd(a,n)$, we conclude from $ax\equiv 1\pmod n$ that $0\equiv ax\equiv 1\pmod d$.

With your ansatz: Assuming that $a$ and $n$ are multiples of $d$, then so is $ax-ny$, so $d\mid 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about going the other way? Contrapositive proof:

If gcd(a,n) = b $\neq$ 1

Then we have the set:

{at + nu: t,u $\in \mathbb{Z}$} = b$\mathbb{Z}$ (quite easy to show why they are equal)

So, lets say n = bq. The next number in b$\mathbb{Z}$ is b(q+1). That means b$\mathbb{Z}$ cannot contain any number $ax \equiv$ 1 mod n. Due to the way I defined the set, it contains all ax such that x $\in \mathbb{Z}$.